# migrate dateadd and datepart from sybase to oracle

Tags: database, oracle, migration, sybase

I tried to migrate this sentence sql from Sybase to Oracle but I don't now how to implement
`dateadd` and `datepart`.

```
select  @v_date = convert(char,convert(char(4),datepart(year, dateadd(month, -13, getdate()))) + "/" + 
         right(( "00" + convert(varchar(2), datepart(month, dateadd(month, -13, getdate())))) , 2) + "/01", 112)
```

I have searched and know Oracle uses `interval` but I still don't understand how.

Comment: If would be helpful if you explained what that statement does in Sysbase. Just as you don't know Oracle SQL most people who know Oracle aren't familiar with Sysbase. This is particularly relevant in the case of date arithmetic, because that is an area where each flavour of RDBMS has invented its own function names and conventions.

Comment: background: `getdate()` returns the current date and time as datatype `datetime`; the various functions are cutting the current date and time into some desired format; I'd suggest updating the question with the output from `select convert(varchar(30),getdate(),109)` and `select @v_date`; this will give us the current date and time as well as the final output; from this someone (with Oracle knowledge) should be able to come up with an equivalent query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Sybase person, but I'm working on the assumption from the code that you want the start of the month that was 13 months ago.

In which case, its:

```
SQL> select trunc(add_months(sysdate,-13),'MM') from dual;

TRUNC(ADD
---------
01-OCT-20
```